# Convert from date to quarter

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

I have the `A1` field with the date in the following format: `2020-01-30`

Need to know the quarter of the date, in my case it should be `1`. Please hint how to do this with the function, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just extract the month number from the date and divide by 3, round the result:

`=INT((MONTH(A1)+2)/3)`